# "No match for 'operator=' in", structs error C++

Tags: c++, struct, operators

When I compile under g++ I get the following errors:

> In function `'int search(int, int, int)'`:
>
> 1584:error: no match for `'operator='` in `'* tt = & core.<anonymous union>::tt[((hash_stack[ply] >> 16) & 2047ul)]'`
>
> 1584:error: note: candidate is:
>
> 118:note: `tt_type& tt_type::operator=(const tt_type&)`
>
> 118:note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from `'tt_type*'` to `'const tt_type&'`

```
static int search(int depth, int alpha, int beta) {
    int                             best_score = -INF;
    int                             best_move = 0;
    int                             score;
    struct move                     *moves;
    int                             incheck = 0;
    struct tt_type                  *tt;                              //LINE 1584
    int                             oldalpha = alpha;
    int                             oldbeta = beta;
    int                             i, count=0;

    nodes++;

    /* test for draw by repetition */
    hash_stack[ply] = compute_hash();
    for (i=ply-4; i>=board[LAST]; i-=2) {
        if (hash_stack[i] == hash_stack[ply]) count++;
        if (count>=2) return 0;
    }

    /*
     *  check transposition table
     */
    *tt = &TTABLE[ ((hash_stack[ply]>>16) & (CORE-1)) ];
    if (tt->hash == (hash_stack[ply] & 0xffffU)) {
        if (tt->depth >= depth) {
            if (tt->flag >= 0) alpha = MAX(alpha, tt->score);
            if (tt->flag <= 0) beta = MIN(beta,  tt->score);
            if (alpha >= beta) return tt->score;
        }
        best_move = tt->move & 07777;
    }
```

Where I have previously defined

```
struct tt_type {                                                       //LINE 118
    unsigned short hash;    /* - Identifies position */
    short move;             /* - Best recorded move */
    short score;            /* - Score */
    char flag;              /* - How to interpret score */
    char depth;             /* - Remaining search depth */
};
```

Comment: And so the long and the short of it is: "no known conversion for argument 1 from 'tt_type*' to 'const tt_type&'"

Answer (score 2):

The most important line in the error message is this:

```
118:note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'tt_type*' to 'const tt_type&'
```

It essentially means that you are trying to assign a pointer to the reference.

Which in turn makes me think that changing `* tt = & core.::tt[((hash_stack[ply] >> 16) & 2047ul)]` in your code to `* tt = core.::tt[((hash_stack[ply] >> 16) & 2047ul)]` for deep copy or to `tt = & core.::tt[((hash_stack[ply] >> 16) & 2047ul)]` for shallow copy will solve the problem (depending on your perspective).

Comment: There's no shallow copy vs deep copy.  One copies an element, the other a pointer.

Comment: @BenVoigt: As long as you got the point :-) They are both deep copies of different things, LOL

Comment: Copying a structure might be shallow or deep, depending on how `operator=` is defined.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your line 1584 is really this one:

```
*tt = &TTABLE[ ((hash_stack[ply]>>16) & (CORE-1)) ];
```

`*tt` is of type `struct tt_type`.  The RHS is of the form `&...`, so it's of some pointer type.  You can assign a struct to a struct, or a pointer to a pointer, but you can't assign a pointer value to a struct (unless you've overloaded the assignment operator).

I haven't studied the code enough to understand it, but you probably want to change `*tt = ...` to `tt = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

```
*tt = &TTABLE[ ((hash_stack[ply]>>16) & (CORE-1)) ];
```

You're trying to store a pointer into a variable that's not a pointer.

You need either

```
*tt = TTABLE[ ((hash_stack[ply]>>16) & (CORE-1)) ];
```

to make a copy of one element of the array (this isn't going to work, since `tt` is not initialized)

or

```
tt = &TTABLE[ ((hash_stack[ply]>>16) & (CORE-1)) ];
```

to make a pointer into the array.

Another way of writing the second version is

```
tt = TTABLE + ((hash_stack[ply]>>16) & (CORE-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
*tt = &TTABLE[ ((hash_stack[ply]>>16) & (CORE-1)) ];
```

You're trying to assign a variable of type `tt_type` to another thing of some other type. I don't know what `TTABLE` is, but as a wild guess, try removing the `&` (the `&` would cause an error if `TTABLE` is an array of `tt_type`s. You'd be trying to assign a `tt_type*` to a `tt_type`).

Answer (score 0):

`*tt = &TTABLE[/**/];`

You're assigning your struct from a pointer.  As clarified by `no known conversion for argument 1 from'tt_type*' to 'const tt_type&'`  It cannot convert the `tt_type*` to a `tt_type&` to make the copy.

I don't know what `TTABLE` is, but I'd remove the `&` from it.